# Chrome extension to mark duplicate tabs?

Tags: chrome

I suffer from tab abuse, namely overuse thereof. Many of my tabs are SE-related, and I tend to end up with two or more tabs pointing to the same page. This contributes to the clutter in my tab bar - I try to kill tabs when I don't need them anymore, but that doesn't always happen.

Thenceforth, I would like to have a Chrome extension that would:

- Automatically detect tabs pointing to the same URL
- Do something to the page or the title, like

  - Prefix the both tab titles with '[dupe]', or
  - Change the tab favicon, or
  - Do something else ingenious like have a dedicated page to keep track of these tabs
- Allow me to say, "no, that's not a duplicate".
- Continually check for these duplicates; I don't want to have to push a button to perform the check.

Is there an extension that does this?

Comment: I use [Only One](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/only-one/ffkdlcmdgpagmbokblekleghfkjgpjdo). Though this doesn't have all the features you seek, but yeah! It would help you prevent tab overuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think despite its terrible name, [Tab Dupectomy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-dupectomy/nkkedbpcfdogedipgdhgeknjdphaplbk) should work for you. It's a lot simpler than what you described:

- Detection of duplicate is automated.
- It doesn't edit the page header, but instead just keeps track of the number of duplicate. A feature that does this is in preparation (see [here](https://github.com/gcode-mirror/tab-dupectomy/issues)).
- Just click on the icon displaying the number to close all duplicates.
- It sometime fails, like in the case of the Google homepage, because it checks for URL, and URL only.

Source code: [Google Code svn repo](http://tab-dupectomy.googlecode.com/svn/), [GitHub](https://github.com/gcode-mirror/tab-dupectomy) mirror

Comment: It's small, fast and easy to use extension, one of the first one which I'm installing on every fresh Chrome instance.

Comment: I think it's not available anymore. Any other alternative? Is there one that changes the look of the tab when it found that it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- [Duplicate Tabs Closer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tabs-closer/gnmdbogfankgjepgglmmfmbnimcmcjle) by *Peuj*

  It automatically detects and closes duplicate tabs (if you choose to) across active or all windows. You can also specify which one to close (older or newer) along with other filters.

For Firefox, see: [Firefox add-on to check or prevent duplicated tabs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/49339/3474)

Comment: Is there one that will change the look of the tabs when it detects they are duplicates?