# Firefox add-on to check or prevent duplicated tabs

Tags: firefox

For Chrome (related [post](https://superuser.com/q/177998/87805)), there is a [Tab Dupectomy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-dupectomy/nkkedbpcfdogedipgdhgeknjdphaplbk) extension.

I am looking for something similar, but for Firefox Quantum.

I have checked few such as [Duplicate Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate-tab/) or [Duplicate This Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate-this-tab/), but these add-ons aren't compatible with Firefox Quantum.

Comment: Tab Dupectomy is LGPL-licensed and the code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/gcode-mirror/tab-dupectomy) -- if you wanted, you could probably port it to Firefox pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [ClickTabUniq](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/clicktabuniq/),

With this Firefox extension, you can close duplicate tabs from the context (right-click) menu on tabs or directly on the page (configurable).

It is fully compatible with Firefox Quantum.

Answer (score 0):

- [Duplicate Tabs Closer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate-tabs-closer/) by *Peuj*

  > Detects and automatically closes duplicate tabs.

  It also supports [Chrome web-browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tabs-closer/gnmdbogfankgjepgglmmfmbnimcmcjle).